# Всплывание окна браузера с сохранением пароля

Tags: javascript

Есть функция на `JS`, которая запрашивает через `AJAX` у сервера ссылку и поcле получения делает так (для скачивания файла):

```
window.location.href = link;
```

В момент после присваивания ссылки и отображения файла для скачивания выскакивает и убирается окно с вопросом сохранения данных для этого сайта.

Тестово пробовал полученную ссылку отобразить как:

```
<a href="полученная ссылка" target="_blank">Текст</a>
```

Это окно не появляется. Куда копать?

[image: Пример окна]

Comment: А как оно вообще появляется, окно это?

Comment: Добавил скрин окна о котором говорю.